# upload excel file to wordpress media from simple php file script

Tags: php, wordpress

I want to upload the excel file to wordpress from outside php file script .I tried to search it but not got.

Can any one help me in this?

Comment: Please elaborate further.

Comment: I am writing php script for uploading excel sheet which already downloaded from another web site report and i want to upload it to wordpress media .

Comment: i tried following code

Comment: $attachment_id = wp_insert_attachment($attachment, $file_path);
$attachment_data = wp_generate_attachment_metadata($attachment_id, $file_path);
wp_update_attachment_metadata($attachment_id, $attachment_data);

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
if ( !function_exists('media_handle_upload') ) {
        require_once(ABSPATH . "wp-admin" . '/includes/image.php');
        require_once(ABSPATH . "wp-admin" . '/includes/file.php');
        require_once(ABSPATH . "wp-admin" . '/includes/media.php');
    }
    $url = "http://example.com/demo.xls";
    $tmp = download_url( $url );
    if( is_wp_error( $tmp ) ){
        // download failed, handle error
    }
    $post_id = 1;
    $desc = "Description";
    $file_array = array();

    // Set variables for storage
    // fix file filename for query strings
    preg_match('/[^\?]+\.(jpg|jpe|jpeg|xls|png)/i', $url, $matches);
    $file_array['name'] = basename($matches[0]);
    $file_array['tmp_name'] = $tmp;

    // If error storing temporarily, unlink
    if ( is_wp_error( $tmp ) ) {
        @unlink($file_array['tmp_name']);
        $file_array['tmp_name'] = '';
    }

    // do the validation and storage stuff
     $id = media_handle_sideload( $file_array, $post_id, $desc );

    // If error storing permanently, unlink
    if ( is_wp_error($id) ) {
        @unlink($file_array['tmp_name']);
        return $id;
    }

    $src = wp_get_attachment_url( $id );
```

Comment: Thanks i will use it and notify you.

Comment: I use that code and got below error
Fatal error: Call to undefined function __() in D:\wamp\www\wordpress\wp-admin\includes\file.php on line 16

Comment: Thanks Sunil! it is working correct. :)

Answer (score 0):

Try this code

```
function upload_user_file( $file = array() ) {
    require_once( ABSPATH . 'wp-admin/includes/admin.php' );
      $file_return = wp_handle_upload( $file, array('test_form' => false ) );
      if( isset( $file_return['error'] ) || isset( $file_return['upload_error_handler'] ) ) {
          return false;
      } else {
          $filename = $file_return['file'];
          $attachment = array(
              'post_mime_type' => $file_return['type'],
              'post_title' => preg_replace( '/\.[^.]+$/', '', basename( $filename ) ),
              'post_content' => '',
              'post_status' => 'inherit',
              'guid' => $file_return['url']
          );
          $attachment_id = wp_insert_attachment( $attachment, $file_return['url'] );
          require_once(ABSPATH . 'wp-admin/includes/image.php');
          $attachment_data = wp_generate_attachment_metadata( $attachment_id, $filename );
          wp_update_attachment_metadata( $attachment_id, $attachment_data );
          if( 0 < intval( $attachment_id ) ) {
            return $attachment_id;
          }
      }
      return false;
}
         if($_FILES['upload']['name']){
     if( ! empty( $_FILES ) ) {
  foreach( $_FILES as $file ) {
    if( is_array( $file ) ) {
   $attachment_id = upload_user_file( $file ); 
    }
  }
}
     }
    }
?>
<form enctype="multipart/form-data" method="post">
    <input type="hidden" name="posted" value="posted"/>
    <input type="file" name="upload"/>
    <input type="submit" value="Save" />
</form>
```

Comment: Thanks but is it possible to upload without giving the html upload form?
Like cron job?

Comment: HI Sunil need help in delete file if already exists?

Comment: If file already exists then in wordpress  file rename by default

Comment: Ok but I want to delete it and then upload new excel sheet using above working code.

Comment: Yes, you can use this code  wp_delete_attachment( $attachment_id);

Comment: thanks I will use this and notify you.